# How to control read timeout globally in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

We're working in a cloud environment and we cannot control DataSource ourselves.
But we would like to enforce a read timeout globally for jdbc calls so that long running SQL can stop because of the timeout and hopefully release the resources afterwards.
Is it something we can do it at JVM layer?

Thanks,

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are asking whether you can *modify the JVM* to achieve your objective?  Probably you could it that way, but if you have access to do that then I don't see how it is possible that you do not also have access to do the job at an easier and more appropriate place.

Comment: It is usually something you control by parameters in the JDBC URL. Consult your database vendor's JDBC documentation.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean with _"we cannot control DataSource ourselves"_?